# Creating a text data frame from multiple XML files

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, text, tei

i am trying to create a single data frame in R, that contains the text from multiple xml files. I have tried to create a function that reads the xmls and uses the xml_text from the xml2 package. This is my code:

```
read_texts <- function(folder) {
  dir_ls(folder, glob = "*.xml") %>%
  map_dfr(
  read_xml(.) %>%
  xml_text(., trim = TRUE) %>%
  tibble()
)
}

read_texts_n <- Vectorize(read_texts)


read_texts_n("forfatterskab")
```

When I'm doing this I still get the error:

```
Error: `x` must be a string of length 1
```

How do I get the code to load my files. The aim is to make a single data frame, that contains all the text. I am not that experienced working with XML.

Comment: @Dave2e Could you provide me with an example of how I would loop this instead of writing data to hundreds of different objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to `Vectorize` your function since you are using `map_dfr`.

Try using the below function.

```
library(xml2)

read_texts <- function(folder) {
  list.files(folder, pattern = '\\.xml$', full.names = TRUE) %>%
    map_dfr(~.x %>% read_xml() %>% xml_text(trim = TRUE) %>%tibble())
}


result <- read_texts_n("forfatterskab")
```

The only doubt I have is the way you pass the folder name. Usually, I would expect you pass a complete folder path to the function. Something like `read_texts_n('Users/username/folder_name')`.

Comment: So, I tried this piece of code and I also tried with the absolute path to the directory, but I am still getting the `x` must be a string of length 1 error. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share what `list.files(folder, pattern = '\\.xml$', full.names = TRUE)` returns for you? Replace `folder` with the absolute path you are using.

Comment: So, I found the mistake here. Turns out I hadn't changed read_text_n to read_texts in the line that creates the results object. It seems to work perfect. It has indeed created a data frame with all the text in it.